Number of 10 digit numbers divisible by 7, whch after interchanging first and unit digit still remain divisible by 7.
RMO 2008 problem 5-
Let $N$ be a ten digit positive integer divisible by $7$. Suppose the first and the last digit of $N$ are interchanged and the resulting number (not necessarily ten digit) is also divisible by $7$ then we say that $N$ is a good integer. How many ten digit good integers are there?
my  initial approach- Let N = ABCDEFGHIJ and number obtained by exchanging A and J , we get JBCDEFGHIA ;
and both are 7k,
$999999999(J-A)=7q $; which is same as
$3^{4}* 37 * 333667 $ (J-A) is a multiple of 7 ; so , we get J-A= 7 or -7 or 0 and we only get
(J,A)= $(8,1)$ and $(9,2)$ ... And This both give rises to 2 case for first and last digit and we can choose the middle 8 digits in $10^{8}$ ways... ;
So the number of numbers are $2 *10^{8} = 200000000$ numbers....
but but but, i realised I'm wrong beacause the choice of middle 8 numbers are not independent they should be in a way that makes N divisible by 7. Hw do I assure this condition? Please give some hints/ideas.

Isn't the last digit the unit digit?  Did you mean the first digit (in the title)?

The title and body disagree. You say first digit and last digit in the body, but the title gives the non-sensical first digit and unit digit.'

You stated "we get J-A= 7", but could it also not be $J-A=-7$ instead?

yah 1. i have made the change in title


@JohnOmielan I thought this wwas pretty much understood moreover it does not really affect the answer, cuz we will just subtract the smaller number from greater


Shouldn't you consider the possibility that $J=0$?

I don't understand your response. How is it "pretty much understood"? Also, it does  affect the result, e.g., where $J=0$, as J. W. Tanner's comment indicates, supports that $A=7$, but not conversely, i.e., $A=0$ and $J=7$ is not a $10$ digit number.

@J.W.Tanner oops I missed that, thanks for pointing it out  but  my original doubt still remains unsolved

yah correct @JohnOmielan , i'm sorry

I would have thought the first and last digits $(J,A)$ could be $(9,2), (8,1), (7,0), (2,9), (1,8)$ and possibly also $(9,9), (8,8), (7,7), (6,6), (5,5), (4,4), (3,3), (2,2), (1,1)$ depending on how you understand the question

@Henry and to evryone, the main problem is not here about what are possible values of J and A but rather how to decide the selection of digits for the middle 8 numbers corresponding to the values of J and A we choose.

Hint: A00000000J is a multiple of 7. So ...

@CalvinLin thanks Mr. Calvin, from this we get 14 possible N, but how do we get other non trivial value N involving different digits satisfying our condition  (I'm calling it trivial because all the digits  between A and J are 0), how did you conclude this? Did this come as a result of genralised answer or we get that after some work on remainders(like 10^3 is -1 mod 7 , then we cube it to get 10^9 congruent  to -1 and since a is congruent to j mod 7 so finally what you have written?moreover divisibilty rule of 7 is also not helpful here , in what possible direction can one think here,

@AlokRajSingh You're completely missing my point. $\quad$ Yes, $ 7 \mid 10^3 + 1$ is a "well-known competition math fact", which is also easily derived.

sorry and thanks

Make the following observations:

$7 \mid A - J$ per OP's work.
There are 18 (NOT 14) possibilities for $(A, J)$ .
$ 7 \mid 10^3 + 1 \mid 10^9 + 1 $
$ 7 \mid A 00000000J$
$7 \mid BCDEFGHI0$
There are 14285714 possibilities for $(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I)$
There are $18 \times 14285714 = 257142852$ total good integers.

